# Redex to remove URL but keep @something

Tags: url

I need to remove URL's but I need to keep strings like @something, this is my redex:

```
"[^@][(https?|ftp|file)://[-a-zA-Z0-9+&#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-zA-Z0-9+&#/%=~_|]]"
```

Nevertheless when I use it to remove strings, it doesn't remove my `http://notwww.things` only those which start with "`http://www`" and it does elminates `@somethings`.

Can anybody help me correct my redex, please?

Comment: I think you mean "regex"

Answer (score 0):

You have should escape dot (`.`)  in character classes. Otherwise this regexp will replace `all` characters.